# How to connect mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in same database, one for pictures and the other table for picture comments. How can i write a sql command to get all the comments belonging to each particular picture?

Comment: general speaking you can join tables with [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). but since you didn't provide enough information about your tables names and column names , no one can write the actual sql statement

Comment: the columns for the picture table are pic_id,pic_owner,pic_insert_date. and the column names for the comments are pic_id,pic_commentor_name,pic_comments.

Comment: You need to use `join` statement with a common id, say pictureid or post_id. Since you did not provide additional details, the general syntax would be something like: `SELECT comment_text, comment_user FROM pictureTable JOIN commentTable ON pictureId`

Comment: @tonclem, provide the table name as well. This is really a basic question, what exactly is your problem or what are you struggling with.

Comment: the table names are picture_table and picture_comment_table

Answer (score 1):

The below code should work. Like I said, this is pretty basic problem and I feel you have some problem related to this. Post what code you tried and edit the question. You can use `WHERE` clause to further filter.

```
SELECT  picture_table.pic_owner,  picture_table.pic_insert_date, picture_comment_table.pic_commentor_name, picture_comment_table.pic_comments FROM
picture_table LEFT JOIN  picture_comment_table 
ON picture_table.pic_id = picture_comment_table.pic_id
```

Comment: when i ran that code on mysql this is what they said "#1052 - Column 'pic_commentor_name' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: In that case mention the table name along with the column. I have edited the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
 $query = "SELECT picture_table.pic_id, picture_comment_table.* 
                FROM picture_table LEFT JOIN picture_comment_table
                ON picture_table.pic_id = picture_comment_table.pic_id";
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
 !$stmt ? die('error') : "";
 $stmt->execute();
```

I used left join since there are some pictures without comments that is not going to be selected in case of an inner join.

also note that if you have more than one comment row for a picture, the result will have more than 1 row for that picture, which a thing you should handle Whether in the application layer (your php code) or in the sql statement.

Comment: Good answer. I missed the php part and about the LEFT Join.

Comment: [

{
"pic_id": "picture100",
"pic_owner": "Stanley Kin",
"pic_insert_date": "23-02-2017",

[
{"pic_commentor_name": "Kim Love",
 "pic_comments": "You look beautifull"
},

{"pic_commentor_name": "John doe Love",
 "pic_comments": "Marvelous you are"
}
]

},

{

"pic_id": "picture101",
"pic_owner": "Linky Nam",
"pic_insert_date": "21-04-2017",

[
{"pic_commentor_name": "Lira Love",
 "pic_comments": "You look Gorgeous"
},

{"pic_commentor_name": "Bram Javan",
 "pic_comments": "love the pics more....."
}
]

}


] but please i need the data to be in this format

Comment: You are welcome. regarding your question This is [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp). database query results are retrieved in tables-like format, you need to convert the result you want to json in the application layer(php code)  using php [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function. But since I don't know how does this pattern is represented in the query result I can't convert it to this json. **you need to include the query result set you want to convert to this json.**

Answer (score 0):

Joining as mentioned above is a good solution.
But you can also relate the two tables via primary key and foriegn key.
Create a primary key field in picture table and create a foriegn key field in comments table.